# How can you pin a header overtop of a UIScrollView that only scrolls in the x dimension?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIScrollView that is displaying some graphical data and it has a x axis at the top of the screen. Currently when you scroll down the x axis disappears because it is just a subview of UIScrollView but I want it pinned to the top of the screen at all times so the user can see the x axis values.

Typically I would just put this axis ontop of the scroll view, so that it doesn't scroll, but I still need it to scroll along with the UIScrollView whenever a horizontal scroll takes place because the x axis does not entirely fit in the view.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I've thought about a few approaches.

1. I could remove the x axis from the ScrollView and then put it in its own UIView and then use the scroll view delegate methods to sync the x axis with the scrollviews new position after and during a horizontal scroll.
2. I could somehow duplicate horizontal scroll events and pass them to the x axis view (which would be another UIScrollView in this case).

I'm hesitant to try number one because I think the animations would be jerky or at the very least out of sync with the horizontal scroll of the scroll view, I would like them to be completely in sync.

I'm hesitant to try number two because I'm not sure if that is even possible to do.

I'm looking for advice on how to approach this problem (preferably from somebody who has done something similar before).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your second approach will work.  Make your view controller a UIScrollViewDelegate for the 2-way scrolling view and use scrollViewDidScroll: to synchronize the positioning by adjusting the scrolling header.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = [scrollView contentOffset];
    CGPoint headOffset = CGPointMake(offset.x, 0.0f);
    [self.headScroller setContentOffset:headOffset animated:NO];
}
```

This assumes that the 'headScroller' has user interaction turned off and has no delegate.  It only scrolls under program control.

Comment: Hey phillip correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't this result in jerky animation? The scroll would take place and then the position of the axis would update after with no animation? I was the axis to scroll, completely in sync, with the main UIScrollView

Comment: In a simple test, there's no perceptible delay.  I *suspect* that would remain true because it seems as if the delegate notification happens before the end of the event cycle where the physical display is refreshed.  The small amount of code isn't enough to look like a delay to the user between the time they make a gesture and the time the views appear to move.  (It's easy enough to try in a dummy app with a couple of arbitrary images.)

Comment: Any manual changes to view frames in `scrollViewDidScroll` are collected by the compositing system and will be drawn in the same draw cycle as the scroll view’s change in position, so it’s the right place to “pin” a view or do any other view repositioning to account for the scroll view’s movement.